# Always got NaN when converting dictionary to multiindex pandas DataFrame if the index including datetime.date object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following example, when a date object is in the index, pandas can not generate DataFrame correctly. Instead of 6, it shows NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

X = {(datetime.date(2020, 6, 3), 'A'): {'B': 6}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(X, orient='index')

print(df)
```

```
               B
2020-06-03 A NaN
```

It's working fine without datetime.date as index.

```
X = {('OK', 'A'): {'B': 6}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(X, orient='index')

print(df)
```

```
      B
OK A  6
```

What's wrong here ? I'm using python 3.8.3 and pandas 1.0.4

Comment: `x = {(pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(2020, 6, 3)),'A'):{'B':6}}` this will gives the correct output but don't why it didnot work with `datetime`.

Comment: @Ch3steR, works. thanks. it's always a headache to deal with date time in general.... for me.

Comment: Glad to have helped. datetime is always a headache for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, a single `datetime` index works fine, a compound `datetime` index with any other type (including another `datetime`) do give `NaN`. The only workaround I have found is to use `pandas` native `datetime`:

```
import pandas as pd

X = {(pd.datetime(2020, 6, 3), 'A'): {'B': 6}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(X, orient='index')

print(df)
```

which yields

```
FutureWarning: The pandas.datetime class is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Import from datetime module instead.
  X = {(pd.datetime(2020, 6, 3), 'A'): {'B': 6}}
              B
2020-06-03 A  6
```

However the warning indicates that this is not a future proof solution and your original form will be the only option (which is currently buggy). I have Python 3.7.6 and pandas 1.0.3.